# How to produce 23$1.4.3445 for JSON in soapUI?

Tags: json, rest, soapui

I have JSON of `"id":"23$1.4.3445"` in which `1.4.3445` is a property stored at the TestCase level. So, I passed `"id":"23$${#TestCase#Uid}"` in POST request expecting to pass `23$1.4.3445` as string. 
But it gives me - `23${#TestCase#Uid}`. It escapes another `$`.

Tried with `$$$` and considering `23$` and `${#TestCase#Uid}` as a separate string and concatenate them but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [dynamic property](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html#2-Dynamic-Properties), which is essentially a Groovy script inside a property. For example:

```
${= '23$' + context.expand( '${#TestCase#Uid}' )}
```